# pagination for list of cards using Array.slice

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm rendering a list of cards to my app. There are 13 in total. I need to show them 3 per page and then I have a button that can be clicked to move along to the next 3, so on and so forth until the end. I'm using the Array.slice method to show the cards. The parameters for the first page are 0 and 3 (`props.trucks.slice(0, 3)`). For the second page, it should be 3 and 6 (`props.trucks.slice(3, 6)`). Clicking the next page button should follow that pattern until cards are exhausted.

I came up with two sets of function for the two sets of cards that I need this previous/next click functionality for. The logic I'm using is running into problems. For example, once I get to the end of the cards for "Nearby Trucks" and try to go by clicking the button with the previous function, it sets the first index in the .slice method to -3, which throws everything off. Once I get to the end of the "Nearby Trucks" cards, the index of the first parameter in .splice is 12. Why is it going from 12 to -3. Can someone look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
    const [nearbySliceParams, setNearbySliceParams] = useState({
        nearbyStart: 0,
        nearbyEnd: 3,
    })

    const [favsSliceParams, setFavsSliceParams] = useState({
        favsStart: 0,
        favsEnd: 3
    })

    const sliceJumpNearby = () => {
        console.log(nearbySliceParams);
        if (nearbySliceParams.nearbyStart >= props.trucks.length - 3) {
            setNearbySliceParams({
                nearbyStart: nearbySliceParams.nearbyStart,
                nearbyEnd: nearbySliceParams.nearbyEnd
            })
        } else {
            setNearbySliceParams({
                nearbyStart: nearbySliceParams.nearbyStart + 3,
                nearbyEnd: nearbySliceParams.nearbyEnd + 3
            })
        }
    }

    const sliceReverseNearby = () => {
        console.log(nearbySliceParams);
        if (nearbySliceParams.nearbyStart = 0) {
            setNearbySliceParams({
                nearbyStart: nearbySliceParams.nearbyStart,
                nearbyEnd: nearbySliceParams.nearbyEnd
            })
        } else {
            setNearbySliceParams({
                nearbyStart: nearbySliceParams.nearbyStart - 3,
                nearbyEnd: nearbySliceParams.nearbyEnd - 3
            })
        }
    }

    const sliceJumpFavs = () => {
        console.log(favsSliceParams);
        if (favsSliceParams.favsStart >= props.favTrucks.length - 3) {
            setFavsSliceParams({
                favsStart: favsSliceParams.favsStart,
                favsEnd: favsSliceParams.favsEnd
            })
        } else {
            setFavsSliceParams({
                favsStart: favsSliceParams.favsStart + 3,
                favsEnd: favsSliceParams.favsEnd + 3
            })
        }
    } 

    const sliceReverseFavs = () => {
        console.log(favsSliceParams);
        if (favsSliceParams.favsStart = 0) {
            setFavsSliceParams({
                favsStart: 0,
                favsEnd: 3
            })
        } else {
            setFavsSliceParams({
                favsStart: favsSliceParams.favsStart - 3,
                favsEnd: favsSliceParams.favsEnd - 3
            })
        }
    }
```

```
         {!props.cuisineTypeMode && <div className="card-div">
                <div className="card-sub-div">
                    <div className="trucks-category-div">
                        <h3 className="trucks-category">Nearby Trucks</h3>
                        <p>View all</p>
                        <div className="category-pagination-arrows">
                            <div className="arrow-bg-div">
                                <i class="fas fa-arrow-left" onClick={sliceReverseNearby}></i>
                            </div>
                            <div className="arrow-bg-div">
                                <i class="fas fa-arrow-right" onClick={sliceJumpNearby}></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="trucks-div">
                        {props.trucks && (props.trucks).slice(nearbySliceParams.nearbyStart, nearbySliceParams.nearbyEnd).map(truck => (
                            <Card className="truck-card" onClick={() => selectTruck(truck.id)}>
                            <CardActionArea>
                                <CardMedia
                                className="truck-img"
                                image={truck.image}
                                style={{ width: '100%' }}
                                />
                                <i 
                                    className="like-icon" 
                                    class={filterThroughFavs(truck.id).length > 0 ? "fas fa-heart" : "far fa-heart"}
                                    onClick={filterThroughFavs(truck.id).length > 0 ? e => removeFromFavorites(e, truck.id) : e => addToFavs(e, truck.id)}
                                />
                                <CardContent>
                                <Typography className="truck-name" gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                                    {truck.name}
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography>
                                    {truck.avg_rating}
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography className="cuisine-type" component="h3">{truck.cuisine_type}</Typography>
                                <Typography className="distance-plus-rating" component="h3">
                                    {truckDistance[truck.index]}
                                    {/* {console.log(`props.location: ${props.location}, truck.current_location: ${truck.current_location}, returns: ${getTruckDistance(props.location, truck.current_location)}`)}
                                    {console.log(getTruckDistance(props.location, truck.current_location))}   */}
                                </Typography>
                                </CardContent>
                            </CardActionArea>
                        </Card>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>}

            {!props.cuisineTypeMode && <div className="card-div">
                <div className="card-sub-div">
                    <div className="trucks-category-div">
                        <h3 className="trucks-category">Your Favorites</h3>
                        <p>View all</p>
                        <div className="category-pagination-arrows">
                            <div className="arrow-bg-div">
                                <i class="fas fa-arrow-left" onClick={sliceReverseFavs}></i>
                            </div>
                            <div className="arrow-bg-div">
                                <i class="fas fa-arrow-right" onClick={sliceJumpFavs}></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="trucks-div">
                        {props.favTrucks && props.favTrucks.slice(favsSliceParams.favsStart, favsSliceParams.favsEnd).map(truck => (
                            <Card className="truck-card" onClick={() => selectTruck(truck.id)}>
                                <CardActionArea>
                                    <CardMedia
                                    className="truck-img"
                                    image={truck.image}
                                    style={{ width: '100%' }}
                                    />
                                    <i 
                                        className="like-icon" 
                                        class={ filterThroughFavs(truck.id).length > 0 ? "fas fa-heart" : "far fa-heart"}
                                        onClick={(e) => removeFromFavorites(e, truck.id)}
                                    />
                                    <CardContent className="truck-contents">
                                    <Typography className="truck-name" gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                                        {truck.name}
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Typography className="cuisine-type" component="h3">{truck.cuisine_type}</Typography>

                                    </CardContent>
                                </CardActionArea>
                            </Card>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out! The problem is that in sliceReverseNearby and sliceReverseFavs, I have a mixup in the if statement's. I'm using the assignment operator where I need to be using the comparison operator.

the code that is incorrect:

```
        if (nearbySliceParams.nearbyStart = 0) {
            setNearbySliceParams({
                nearbyStart: nearbySliceParams.nearbyStart,
                nearbyEnd: nearbySliceParams.nearbyEnd
            })
        }
```

```
        if (favsSliceParams.favsStart = 0) {
            setFavsSliceParams({
                favsStart: 0,
                favsEnd: 3
            })
        }
```

should be:

```
        if (nearbySliceParams.nearbyStart === 0) {
            setNearbySliceParams({
                nearbyStart: nearbySliceParams.nearbyStart,
                nearbyEnd: nearbySliceParams.nearbyEnd
            })
```

```
        if (favsSliceParams.favsStart = 0) {
            setFavsSliceParams({
                favsStart: 0,
                favsEnd: 3
            })
        }
```